# Properties in list has changed when using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I don't know why item in list has been changed when i using lambda expression.
here my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class test
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string no { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static List<test> a;
    public static List<test> b = new List<test>();      

    public static List<test> a_list() 
    {
        List<test> c = new List<test>();
        c.Add(new test() { id = "_01", name=null, no="1"});
        c.Add(new test() { id = "_02", name=null, no="2"});
        return c;
    }   

    public static void Main()
    {
        a = a_list();
        string key = "_01";
        //
        test i = new test();
        i = a.First(x => x.id.Equals(key));
        i.name = "xxxxxxx";
        b.Add(i);
        //
        Console.WriteLine("id:"+a[0].id+"\nName:"+a[0].name+"\nno:"+a[0].no);
        Console.WriteLine("id:"+b[0].id+"\nName:"+b[0].name+"\nno:"+b[0].no);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is result
id:_01
Name:xxxxxxx
no:1
id:_01
Name:xxxxxxx
no:1

Why a[0] equals "xxxxxxx"? (sorry my english is bad )

Comment: Not really understanding what you're asking here - `First(…` returns a reference to the test object, which you then change. What were you expecting to happen? And what do you want to happen?

Comment: Because that's what you set it to. Are you expecting that assignment not to work?

Comment: Well you are only asking for the first one by using `First`

Comment: Thank you for replying But I've just added the variable "i" to the list "b" then why does the elements in list "a" also change?

Answer (score 3):

here:

```
i = a.First(x => x.id.Equals(key));
i.name = "xxxxxxx";
```

`i` and `a.First()` are now references to the same object.  Modifying a property on that object will affect both of these, because they are pointers to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what your code does is:

- It creates a list with two elements (`a`)
- It takes its first element and modifies that element's value
- It takes that element and adds it to the second list (`b`)

So the outcome is that you have two lists - one (`a`) contains two elements, the other (`b`) just one, but (and here's the important bit) - it's the exact same element as the first one in `a`. So when you write the first element of both lists, the results are equal.

Comment: Thank you for replying But I've just added the variable "i" to the list "b" then why does the elements in list "a" also change?

Comment: Because first element in `a` is `i` - it's the first element of both. You can't think of a list in terms of physical boxes - rather think about a list of places where I can find actual objects. Both your lists (at least on the first element) point to the same object - the one that you've just modified.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a camera pointing at a car. When the car door opens, you see it through the camera, **but the camera is not the car**.

Now your friend some distance away also points his camera at the car. You both can see the door open and close, and the lights, etc.

A variable is like the camera and the car is the object it points to.
If you turn off or destroy one of the cameras, the car is still there. In fact, if you destroy both cameras the car is still there (until garbage collection).

See this excellent article: http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/04/28/foundations-of-programming-pt-7-back-to-basics-memory/